# Why can not add mdf file to visual studio

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I try to add a mdf file to app_data in mvc. Everytime I get Microsoft visual studio alert with this:

> "The file can not be opened because it is being used by another
>   process,  please close all applications that might access this file
>   and try again."

I disconnected sql and closed it. I then closed all applications and only visual studio was on. I still get the alert. Only when I restart my computer the alert is off.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an open connection to the MDF in Server Explorer or via any other tools?

Answer (score 0):

MDF files are *generally* used by a separate SQL Server process.
You would normally change and query data by communicating with this server, not by trying to use it's data files directly.

If you can add some more context around your problem -- including what software you are using and what you have tried -- you might get better answers than this.

Comment: I am doing the MvcMusicStore of Microsoft http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access
I am doing it step by step and still I get this alert.

Comment: Does step 3, "Verify the connection to the database" work for you? Are you getting the database icon, or a generic file icon?

Comment: No it tells me the file is in use althought everything is close, do you know about a way to check it ?

Comment: Have you opened the file from Windows Explorer (i.e. as a normal file)? Do you have SQL Server or Sql Server Express installed? It sounds like something else is contending for the file. If possible, I'd recommend deleting the Solution and MDF file, download everything from scratch and start again.

Comment: Well i used the task manager to stop all proccesses with sql word in them, and it helped.. but I am sure that there is a better and right way to overcome this problem..

Comment: That sounds like a Sql Server process was running and keeping a lock on the file -- as the error suggests. If this happens every time you start your computer, the MDF might be bound to your sql server instance.